# Installing Ubuntu with Windows installer on Windows 8 machine

Tags: installation, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I have a Windows 8 Ultrabook. I downloaded Ubuntu (release 12.04) and installed using the Windows installer (Wubi).

On rebooting at the end of the installation, I get the Windows boot screen asking if I want to boot into Windows 8 or Ubuntu. I select Ubuntu, and I get an error message that says Ubuntu is missing a boot file or has errors.

Please let me know how to fix, or if my procedure is incorrect.

Comment: Wubi doesn't work with UEFI boot: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/694242 (Check if this applies to you - if the computer is new with secure boot, then it likely does)

Answer (score 2):

Especially if your ultrabook came with Windows 8, there is a good chance that it is UEFI with secure boot on, you may need to turn this off for even the Wubi install, and definitely need to if you are to try and install grub. Otherwise, I you may want to try and remove it (with wubi you can remove in programs/features in control panel), double check the md5 of your ubuntu iso, and reinstall.

Comment: I'd go with a normal dual boot, otherwise you'd have to switch to hybrid boot as wells as replace the GPT partition table on the disk with MBR partition table. There's a bunch of info here (can't vouch for it): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has a bootloader issue , I though came from Windows 8 to Ubuntu using a Bootable USB Drive , No problems but I removed Windows Completely , I do say one thing , That you should try going in BIOS and removing Safe Lock (Secure boot (?))Bootloader , It makes it so that you can only boot Winodws Successfully but makes other OS's harder to boot , Disable and it might help , Cheers!